# Change default launcher on Amazon Fire 5th Generation

Tags: android

I have an Amazon Fire 5th generation running Fire OS 5.3.2 and wish to change the default launcher to Nova Launcher. How can I achieve this? My device is currently not rooted, but I want to root it, so if you know how to root Fire OS 5.3.2, let me know. I am comfortable using adb. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is no root yet for the Fire 7 (2015) tablet running Fire OS 5.3.2, but you can boot into recovery and ADB sideload OS 5.3.1.0 which is rootable using Kingroot. Don't try to downgrade to an earlier version than OS 5.3.1.0 or you will brick it. The best place is Rootjunky's website. Check out his supertool for this device. With the supertool you can root with Kingroot, install SuperSU and Nova Launcher. It has other useful functions too.

Edit. See link for confirmation of rollback and references within for the procedure: http://forum.xda-developers.com/amazon-fire/general/fireos-5-3-2-arrived-t3500922

Comment: Are you sure you can downgrade to Fire OS 5.3.1 without bricking? How can I do this?